# How to show $h=g$ a.e. $[m]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $R^k$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of the Borel measurable subsets of $R^k$.

If $\mu$ is a positive bounded measure on $\mathfrak M$ and $\mu\ll m$, We also have $\mu|_{\mathfrak B}\ll m|_{\mathfrak B}$.

By The Theorem of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym, there is a unique $h\in L^1(m)$ such that $\mu(E)=\int_Eh\,dm$ for every set $E\in \mathfrak M$, and a unique  $g\in L^1(m|_{\mathfrak B})$ such that $\mu|_{\mathfrak B}(S)=\int_Sg\,d(m|_{\mathfrak B})$ for every set $S\in \mathfrak B$.

Do we have $h=g$ a.e. $[m]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S \in \mathfrak{B}$. It's not difficult to prove that

$$\int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m|_{\mathfrak{B}}$$

given that the second integral exists (which is true in our case). Now

$$\int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m|_{\mathfrak{B}} =\mu |_{\mathfrak{B}}(S) = \mu(S) = \int \limits_S h \, \mathrm{d} m.$$

Now if $E \in \mathfrak{M}$, there is $S \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $m(E \Delta S) = 0$. Thus

$$\int \limits_E g \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m + \int \limits_{E \setminus S} g \, \mathrm{d} m - \int \limits_{S \setminus E} g \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_S g \, \mathrm{d} m$$

and similarly $\displaystyle \int \limits_E h \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_S h \, \mathrm{d} m$, hence $\displaystyle \int \limits_E g \, \mathrm{d} m = \int \limits_E h \, \mathrm{d} m = \mu(E)$. By uniqueness in the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem we get $g = h$ in $L^1(m)$.